# How can I convert a boolean matrix into a greyscale map?

Tags: matplotlib, colormap, mandelbrot

I am trying to visualize the Mandelbrot Set so it can be like the image like this(https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeaHorseValley.html).
I have the function that returns a boolean array with True indicating It is a part of the Mandelbrot set and False that it is not.

```
def mandelbrot(x, y, dx, dy, dims=(300, 400), threshold=25, iterations=200):
    '''Returns a boolean matrix of the given dimensions, indicating whether a
    position inside the rectangle spanning from (x, y) to (x+dx, y+dy) is part of
    the Mandelbrot set or not'''
    xs, ys = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(x, x + dx, dims[1]),
                         np.linspace(y, y + dy, dims[0]))
    c = xs + ys * 1j
    zs = np.zeros(dims, dtype=np.complex128)
    for i in range(iterations):
        abs_zs = np.abs(zs)
        zs[abs_zs < threshold] = zs[abs_zs < threshold] ** 2 + c[abs_zs < threshold]
    return np.abs(zs) < threshold
```

I guess this code above doesn't really matter though when I input (-1.5,-1,2,2), it returns an array like this below.

```
array([[False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       ...,
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, ..., False, False, False]])
```

And the result I want is following below. I have no idea how I should approach this. Could you at least suggest tools I can use or hints if you have any ideas? Thank you already in advance!

[image]

Comment: `plt.imshow(your_arr, cmap='gray')` would do.

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/examples/showcase/mandelbrot.html

Comment: To get more grey values, you might try to `return np.abs(zs) / threshold`. Also, you could try to increase the `dims=(1200, 1600)` or so. Maybe a different colormap: `plt.imshow(mandelbrot(-1.5, -1, 2, 2, dims=(1200, 1600)), cmap='inferno')`?